# Witdh Ratio Scale not applying in Android Layout constrain

Tags: android

I am learning Android, and doing some exercice, following a tutorial, when applying the Witdh ratio to an imageView, it doesn't work. The strange this is that when applying the same to the Height it works. After doing some research I thing that I am doing things right, but some reason it doesn't apply.
I apreciate some help to solve this.
thanks.

I want to do the 2:3. In the picture the Witdh doesn't work.
[image]

But when doing the Height it works.
[image]

The Viewimage i want to apply ratio is ImageViewPoster:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewPoster"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2Lady"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,2:3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2Lady"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.48"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/poster" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2Lady"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/header" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="Beaty and the Beast "
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2Lady" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,2:3"` then it means height will be first computed from other constraints and then width will be adjusted according to the aspect ratio. Therefore, when you give the height value, the width value is set.

Your Code

```
  <ImageView
       .
       .
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,2:3"
        />
```

Comment: As you can see in the first image, the witdh value is not applied, and the image doesn't have witdh.

Comment: w,2:3 -> your problem

Comment: Yes, but I need help to solve this problem. Do I need to change anything in order the witdh is applied on the design?
I did change to   h,2:3 but didn't make any difference.

Comment: h and w please removed.

Comment: I have remove h and w, and nothing has change, the witdh is not applied, as the first image shown above. And Android studio, adds dinnamically the w to the code, when you set the ratio on the attributs design.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio to the **witdth** works only when the view has no constrains.

[image]